# Using .text() to get formatting of JSON data

Tags: json, formatting

I'm using:

```
function pipeCallback(obj) {
```

to get the contents of a Yahoo pipe (in JSON).  I then create a string inside:

```
document.write("<div......);
var buildstring = ".......;
document.write(buildstring);
document.write("</div>");
```

Everything works, except that one item in the string:

```
obj.value.items[x].description.content
```

contains a lot of text and is stripped of its formatting.  Is there a way to define a var (using .text()?) to keep the formatting and then to use the defined term in the string - e.g. something like:

```
var description = (obj.value.items[x].description.content).text()
```

and then to use the term 'description' in buildstring in place of obj.value.items[x].description.content.

Thanks for any suggestions/help.

EDIT

@Barmar Thanks.  I tried that (I think...):

```
var description = function() {return (obj.value.items[x].description.content).text()};

var buildstring = "<table><tr><img src=" + imageurl  + "> <b>" + obj.value.items[x].title + "</b><br /><td>" + description() + "</td></tr></table><br />";
```

(imageurl is a separately defined variable).  I think I must have missed the point of your suggestion (or not given the right information at first).  Anyhow..it didn't work.

EDIT #2

```
function pipeCallback(obj) {
document.write("<div id=testdiv><b>LATEST NEWS</b><hr>");
var x;
for (x = 0; x < obj.count ; x++)
{

var imageurl = (typeof obj.value.items[x]["media:content"] == 'undefined') ? "http://default.png" : obj.value.items[x]["media:content"].url;

var buildstring = "<table><tr><img src=" + imageurl  + "> <b>" + obj.value.items[x].title + "</b><br /><td>" + obj.value.items[x].description.content + "</td></tr></table><br />";
document.write(buildstring);
buildstring = null;
}
document.write("</div>");

}
```

Comment: Does it work when you use the long form that you spelled out? My answer is just a way to abbreviate that expression, it doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: @Barnar - it works in the original form (i.e without the 'var description') when I have just the second line of code above with obj.value.items[x].description.content instead of description().  The only thing is that then, of course, I get unformatted text.  Thanks

Comment: I thought you were using that with `.text()` at the end. Does that work? If it does, then so should my version -- it's just a shorter way of writing the same thing. I don't really understand what you're trying to do with that, though; I don't see how you expect it to create formatting that's not there.

Comment: No, it doesn't work that way.  All I'm trying to do is get all the <p>....</p> tags that are in the JSON object.  At the moment I just get one long block of text - even though when I look at the feed in Yahoo Pipes the paragraphs are displayed.  I've put the relevant part of the full code above (which works).  Thanks.

Comment: I'm at a loss. If the tags were in the original JSON string, I don't know why they would have been removed when you parsed it; JSON doesn't try to interpret the contents of strings. And I can't think of a way to get them back if they were removed. What API are you using to parse the JSON?

Comment: The only code, other than that at Edit 2 above) is a reference to the src=yahoo pipe address/id &_render=json&_callback=pipeCallback (which gives the function pipeCallback(obj) at the start above).  Then, it's just var buildstring that grabs the obj values.  I replaced the `<p>` tags with &nbsp; (using the regex module) - and the spaces are preserved in the output.  It seems it's only html tags in `<..>` that is ignored at document.write(buildstring) - which makes me think it's something in my script, not in the JSON (that's why I looked at .text() as an option).  Thanks for trying.

Comment: I'm not even sure what you expected .text() to do. It's not a standard Javascript method on strings. There's a jQuery .text() method -- it's used to get or set the text contents of a node in the DOM. But you're trying to use it on a string, not a jQuery object.  What makes you think the pipe is returning data with formatting in it in the first place? If the pipe is returning plain text, there's no way to add formatting.  If it has plain-text formatting like blank lines, maybe what you need is to wrap it with `<pre>...</pre>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
var description = function() {return (obj.value.items[x].description.content).text()};
```

and then use `description()` to get this.